# When switching between tabbarcontroller items viewwillappear is not called swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I have a project which I embedded into a `UITabBarController`.  When I switch tabs `viewWillAppear` is not called.  All other functions of the `TabBarController` work except for this.  I want the project to update the text of a `textview` from a json file from a web server.  I log from `viewWillAppear` and it only appears the first time the view is loaded. Do I need to force `viewWillAppear` to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` of the `UITabBarController` will not get called (and it shouldn't) when you switch tabs, because it never actually disappeared to be appearing again.

You can use `viewWillAppear` of the viewControllers inside `UITabBarController` (it will get called every time you select this viewController), or the tabbarcontroller's delegate methods like

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

Good luck!